# Proxy_pass to url NGINX with a Meteor Server

Tags: nginx, meteor, reverse-proxy

I have configured a meteor server and setup the nginx configuration. The route works however when configuring dynamic subdomains to point to a specific part of the web app it produces a 404 error on the browser when loading the meteor file.

I am attempting to direct all `*.domain.com` to `http://localhost:3000/booking/`

My configuration is:

```
server {

        server_name *.domain.com;
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/booking/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
         }

}
```

The 404 occurs in the Meteor JS file.

[image]

If I remove the above nginx subdomain configuration and go to a subdomain it works perfectly, loading the route application. I assume I am missing something to load the application correctly.

The issue only occurs when I `proxy_pass` to a route within the URL `<url>/booking`

Comment: Your url becomes `http://localhost:3000/booking/380......js?meteor....`, which I assume is totally invalid? That's why the 404. It is located at `http://localhost:3000/3850....js` ?

Comment: yeah the root URL changes and needs to point to the root which is without the `booking`. How do I do this?

Comment: @Allreadyhome, so, the whole thing works if you do remove `/booking/` from `proxy_pass`? Then what doesn't work — what do you actually want to do, and what problems do you have doing it?!

Comment: @Allreadyhome did you gave my settings a try?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar setup, where I have configured different Meteor applications on several subdomains plus a static website on the domain root, all pointing interlly to different ports.

Here is my setup step by step.

**Folder structure, location and proxy pass**

First thing to think about is the folder strucutre. Depending on your subdomain's VHost-root directory there is a relative path to your subdomain's application folder.

Imagine the following setup:

```
/www (dir, usually under /var)
  /domain (dir)
    /websitexy (dir, a static website is deployed under this dir)
    /subdomain (dir)
      /books (dir, subdomain app is deployed under this dir)
```

For such a setup I made my nginx config to point to the app's location within the subdomain:

```
location /books {
```

I had a similar issue when first time starting my app. One thing I found out is, that my config worked, when setting proxy_pass on my private `ip/port` combination:

```
proxy_pass http://172.x.x.x:3000;
```

This also involves to remove the route name (`/books`) adter the port number on this entry. Now your proxy pass involves all routing within your subdomain.

**Note on routing**

Note, that there can be confusion about routing here. By setting the `location` property you set the routing on the nginx level (server's directory structure), which is why there is no route within your proxy pass.

Your application may have it's own internal routing defined. It is important, that you app's internal router retrieves all requests based from it's application ur root. This is why it is important to have the proxy pass not to include any path after the port number.

**Websocket**

I have read some articles on [nginx and websocket](https://www.nginx.com/blog/websocket-nginx/) connections. Basically my initial settings came from this article and looked like from [this documentation article](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html):

```
location /app {
    proxy_pass 172.x.x.x;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
}
```

I also had to add a `proxy_read_timeout` and `proxy_send_timeout` because there was an issue with the websocket protocol otherwise:

> By default, the connection will be closed if the proxied server does
>   not transmit any data within 60 seconds. This timeout can be increased
>   with the proxy_read_timeout directive

So I also set the timeout values:

```
proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
proxy_send_timeout 36000s;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Read more on this [here](https://ma.ttias.be/enable-keepalive-connections-in-nginx-upstream-proxy-configurations/) and [here](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_read_timeout).

Summarizing my setup looks like the following (using your app credentials):

```
location /books {
    proxy_pass http://172.x.x.x:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_send_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

So to solve your case, you may check on your vhost directory (the one where your app is deployed, see folder structure above) and change your `location` and `proxy_pass` setting accordingly.

If this is not working, you may need to add some more output of your errors, e.g. a excerpt of the log when attempt to connect.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of solving the issue.

**1 - In case of 404 try a fallback option without booking in url**

```
server {

        server_name *.domain.com;
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/booking/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
         }

      location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }

}
```

**2 - Have a separate block for js and css**

```
server {

        server_name *.domain.com;
        listen 80;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/booking/;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; #for websockets
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
         }

      location ~ \.(js|css|font)$ {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/$request_uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
      }

}
```

Comment: Doing this produces `proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression` error

Comment: This succesfully allows a restart of the nginx server but the same 404 issue exists where the project cannot find the Meteor JS. You can see this by going here bob.badgerbookings.com. Going to http://badgerbookings.com/ loads the project fine.

Comment: can you try adding `proxy_intercept_errors on;` also to this config? I think I may have missed that and it case 404 to be replied to client directly

Comment: Still the same 404 error when tested with both configurations. I wonder if something needs set in the Meteor project?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164750/discussion-between-tarun-lalwani-and-allreadyhome).